Use Selected Data from Userform to Reference Other Cell in row containing userform data
I have the following code. The data selected in listquotes on my user form comes from a column of data on a table, i need this value that I selected to be used as a reference (quotenumber) to transfer data from the same row to another sheet.
I keep getting the message "Please select a Quote # from the ListQuotes ComboBox." even when a quote number is selected.
Sub TransferDataBasedOnQuote()
    Dim wsTaskCodes As Worksheet
    Dim wsInvoiceForm As Worksheet
    Dim quoteNumber As String
    Dim quoteRow As Range
    Dim projectNameCell As Range
    Dim pridCell As Range
    Dim billCodeCell As Range
    
    ' Set references to the worksheets
    Set wsTaskCodes = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Task Codes")
    Set wsInvoiceForm = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Invoice Log and Form")
    
    ' Show the FormQuotes UserForm to select the quote number
    FormQuotes.Show
    
    ' Get the selected quote number from the form's Tag property after closing
    quoteNumber = FormQuotes.ListQuotes.Tag
    
    ' Ensure that a valid quote number was selected
    If quoteNumber = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please select a Quote # from the ListQuotes ComboBox.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Find the Quote # in column A of Task Codes sheet
    Set quoteRow = wsTaskCodes.Columns("A").Find(quoteNumber, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    
    ' If Quote # is not found, show a message and exit
    If quoteRow Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Quote # not found. Please try again.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Find "Project Name:" and transfer data
    Set projectNameCell = wsInvoiceForm.Cells.Find(What:="Project Name:", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not projectNameCell Is Nothing Then
        projectNameCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = quoteRow.Offset(0, 1).Value ' Assuming "Project Name" is in the second column (B)
    Else
        MsgBox "'Project Name:' not found in Invoice Form", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Find "Project ID:" and transfer data
    Set pridCell = wsInvoiceForm.Cells.Find(What:="Project ID:", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not pridCell Is Nothing Then
        pridCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = quoteRow.Offset(0, 8).Value ' Assuming "Project ID" is in the 9th column (I)
    Else
        MsgBox "'Project ID:' not found in Invoice Form", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Find "Billing Code" and transfer data
    Set billCodeCell = wsInvoiceForm.Cells.Find(What:="Bill to Task Code:", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not billCodeCell Is Nothing Then
        billCodeCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = quoteRow.Offset(0, 9).Value ' Assuming "Billing Code" is in the 10th column (J)
    Else
        MsgBox "'Billing Code:' not found in Invoice Form", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Add more transfers as needed based on your structure
    
    ' Notify the user of the successful transfer
    MsgBox "Data successfully transferred for Quote # " & quoteNumber, vbInformation
End Sub


FormQuotes.ListQuotes.Tag can only retrieve the pre-defined Tag (which is set in userform design mode) after closing the userform. Any changes made to it via code will be lost once the userform is unloaded. In most cases, ListQuotes.Value is used to obtain the item selected by the user in the ComboBox.
I recommend using a public variable declared in a standard module to store the user selection. Retrieve the selected item from the ComboBox during the Change event.
Standard Module
Public pQuote As String

Sub TransferDataBasedOnQuote()
    '.. your code
    
    ' Show the FormQuotes UserForm to select the quote number
    FormQuotes.Show
    
    ' Get the selected quote number from the form's Tag property after closing
    quoteNumber = pQuote
    
    ' Ensure that a valid quote number was selected
    If quoteNumber = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please select a Quote # from the ListQuotes ComboBox.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ' .. your code
End Sub

FormQuotes Module
Private Sub FormQuotes_Change()
    pQuote = Me.FormQuotes.Value
End Sub

